# Return the number of rows with where condition

Tags: codeigniter

In Codeigniter, how do I return the number of rows with a where condition?

Comment: [$this->db->count_all_results()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html). 5s search on google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->db->where('title', 'Book');
$this->db->from('my_table');
echo $this->db->count_all_results();
// Produces an integer, like 17
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like:

```
$this->db->where('firstname','gautam');
        $query = $this->db->get('rebels');            
        return $query->num_rows();
```

it will also return the number of rows resulting... :-)

Answer (score -1):

Use count() :

```
$this->db->where('title', 'abc');
$this->db->from('articles');
$query = $this->db->get();
return count($query->result());
```

Comment: With this you have to query all the results, but with count_all_resuls(), you only need to count them, not query all of them.